# Passing enum command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, enums, console-application, command-line-arguments

So I have this switch in order to set a wait time

```
public int Option(string arg)
{
    switch (arg)
    {
        case "/t:Max":
                return 0;
        case "/t:Med":
                return 1000;
        case "/t:Min":
               return 2000;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I use enum for /t:Min, /t:Med, /t.Max in order to replace the switch?

Indeed something like:

```
enum t
{
    /t:Min,
    /t:Med,
    /t:Max
};
```

Comment: Enum.TryParse() comes to mind...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: While that replaces the string with an enum, it won't remove the need for the switch. Unless the numbers are encoded in the enum constants, which I would probably call a hack :-)

Comment: You'll have to lose the /t: part.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: true in the strict sense.  Though he could number the enum values with the integer values he requires.

Comment: my suppervisor wats the program to have /t:something... so that's not really an option

Comment: The question is whether you should really use an `enum` type here. If the enum just serves for recognizing whether a given *string* is in a given list of *strings*, I'd argue that the switch over strings is the more elegant solution. Reflecting on an `enum` seems a bit like abusing the .NET infrastructure for user input validation.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: `enum` is perfectly fine. I would say it is the more elegant solution than switch over strings. Switching over strings means that the context of the switch cases will need to be implicitly shared between all blocks of code that need to parse the args. This can be quite messy, IMHO.

Comment: @code4life: When using `enum`, an otherwise straightforward new requirement such as supporting a user-defined list of custom values means that you have to replace the whole evaluation code, whereas this is no problem as long as you compare identifiers input by users with strings. Enums are surely fine for very limited sets of values that are unlikely to change, but in this case we are looking at three string identifiers for arbitrary values from a set of possibly 2001 values in total. So, the OP should be aware of the possible difficulties `enum` might bring in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your enumeration should be like this:

```
public enum WaitTime 
{
     Min, Max, Med
}
```

and convert your switch to this:

```
switch ((WaitTime)Enum.Parse(typeof(WaitTime), arg.Replace("/:", string.Empty)))
{
    case WaitTime.Max:
            return 0;
    case WaitTime.Med:
            return 1000;
    case WaitTime.Min:
           return 2000;
    default:
           return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Enum.Parse` of `TryParse`. Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx

But still you would have to retrieve the string from the command line arguments (strip the '/t:') and parse it into your `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public enum t
{
  [Description("/t:Min")]  // <<---- set the string equivalent of the enum HERE.
  min = 0,  // <<---- set the return value of the enum HERE.

  [Description("/t:Med")]
  med = 1000,

  [Description("/t:Max")]
  max = 2000
}
```

You'll also need this handy little class:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static list_of_t = Enum.GetValues(typeof(t)).Cast<t>().ToList();

    // returns the string description of the enum.
    public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can use the decorated enum like this to get what you need:

```
public int Option(string arg)
{
  // get the matching enum for the "/t:" switch here.
  var foundItem = 
      EnumHelper.list_of_t.SingleOrDefault(c => c.GetEnumDescription() == arg);

  if (foundItem != null)
  {
    return (int)foundItem;  // <<-- this will return 0, 1000, or 2000 in this example.
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

HTH...

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
enum YourEnum
{
    Min,
    Med,
    Max
};

void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arg0 = args[0]; // "/t:Min"
    var arg0arr = arg0.Split(':') // { "/t", "Min" }
    var arg0val = arg0arr[1]; // "Min"
    var e = Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnum), arg0val);
}
```

Call app:

```
app.exe /t:Min
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't the most simple way just to make a dictionary with arg as key and time as value, and use .TryGetValue() and if that fails just return 0?

Someting like this :
The arguments.Add could be happening in the constructor, dosn't need to be in the method.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, int> arguments = new Dictionary<string, int>(5);

    public int Option(string arg)
    {
        arguments.Add("Max", 0);
        arguments.Add("Med", 1000);
        arguments.Add("Min", 2000);

        int value;
        if (arguments.TryGetValue(arg.Replace("/:", string.Empty), out value))
            return value;
        //default
        return 0;
    }
```